# Moving files into specific directories based on filetypes

Tags: bash, shell-script, files

I am having a bit of bother with a control flow statement for a small interactive script I have which sorts and processes unsorted files from a desktop folder.

The script takes in a series of arguments through the command line

`jpg` `gif` `docx`

And then iterates through an unsorted folder pulling all types of that file to newly created desktop directories.

Its working great to a point, but the issue I have is,  how to get the remaining file types (.wav png midi and a whole plethora of other types) in that unsorted folder automatically moved to a new miscellaneous folder that needs to be created when the original argument of `jpg gif docx` above is executed.

The part after `done` I can not get to run.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Good Morning, Please enter your file type name for sorting [ENTER]:" all_extensions
if cd /Users/christopherdorman/desktop
  then  while read extension
      do    destination="folder$extension"
        mkdir -p "$destination"
        mv  -v unsorted/*."$extension" "$destination"
      done   <<< "${all_extensions// /$'\n'}"
    if mv  -v unsorted/* "foldermisc"
      then  echo "Good News, the rest of Your files have been successfully processed"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: why is this been edited

Comment: Is this the full script or just a part of it?

Comment: full script. .....It runs. its the bit after done  which starts <<< I can not get the remaining file types done

Comment: It looks like you need to `mkdir -p foldermisc` before you try to `mv` there.

Comment: @NathanWilson Can I just thank you for that. I have asked this question on numerous sites and no one has chirped in with the answer. that worked

Comment: Syntax Killer, if Nathan's comment  answered your question, then I'd encourage @NathanWilson to post it as an actual Answer.

Comment: Glad it worked. I'll post my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to `mkdir -p foldermisc` before you try to `mv` there.